# Angular 5 post object from dropdownlist

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to add a worker to a job from a dropdownlist and I do not understand how to write this in typescript. I am very new to Angular and Typescript so this can be basic for you but I want to learn and google isn't very helpful on this or I don't know how to search this specific problem.
To make it clear I will add the models from web api too.

**Job:**

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Worker> Worker { get; set; }
}
```

**Worker:**

```
public class Worker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Job> Job { get; set; }
}
```

So there will be generated a table between these two tables where I want to store all Workers assigned to a Job. 
When I add a new Job I have populated a DropDownlist with all the workers available and I want to select a worker and submit with the rest of inputs.

Here are the models from Angular:

**Jobs:**

```
export class Jobs {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
  Description: string;
  DueDate: Date;
  IsCompleted?: boolean;

  worker: Worker[];
}
```

**Worker:**

```
export class Worker {
  Id: number;
  FirstName: string;
  LastName: string;
}
```

**Jobs Service:**

```
addJob(jobs: Jobs): Observable<Jobs> {
    return this.http.post<Jobs>(this.apiURL, jobs, httpOptions);
}
```

Ok so far I am pretty sure everything is alright, from now on there are 2 important problems:

1. I am not sure how to bind correctly the DropDownlist for posting data.
2. I don't know how to pass the object that I am taking from DropDownlist into the TypeScript component and send it to the service.

**HTML Component Dropdownlist:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="labelInputs">Select Worker</label><br>
        <select [(ngModel)]="workers" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">Select Worker</option>
          <option *ngFor="let worker of workers" value="worker">{{worker.FirstName}} {{worker.LastName}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

**Submit button of inputs and DropDownlist:**

```
  <button class="brn btn-lg btn-block btn-change" (click)="add(name.value, desc.value, workers)">Add Job</button>
```

**TypeScript add method:**

```
jobs: Jobs[];
workers: Worker[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.getJobs();
    this.getWorkers();
}

add(Name: string, Description: string, worker: object): void {
    this.jobsServices.addJob({Name, Description, worker } as Jobs)
        .subscribe(jobs => {
            this.jobs.push(jobs);
        });
}
```

I tried various things to pass the worker object, but at least this reaches my API but fails ModelState because I am not receiving any worker because first of all binding is wrong and in console I get "worker" for parameter worker not an actual object.

"*ERROR Error: Error trying to diff 'worker'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed*"

I appreciate any help, tutorials, links, explanations or what to modify here.

Comment: What do `getJobs` and `getWorkers` do?

Comment: I use these in other methods like "GetWorkers: void.... or getJobs():void....". I have a list of jobs in the same html component, I didn't pasted that because is irrelevant. Its already a long post to read.

Comment: Why did you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes:

- Add a variable `worker: Worker` to your TS
- On `<select>`, change `[(ngModel)]="workers"` to `[(ngModel)]="worker"`.
- On `<option>`, change `value` to `[value]`. `[]` is Property Binding, if you don't have `[]` around value, what you pass in the `value` is actually the string `worker`.
- Your function now take in `worker` instead of `workers`.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I didn't knew about [value] so I got to learn that but now my console shows: `Name = "sadsa", Description = "sadsa", worker = "[object Object]"` when I am submitting. and I get a 400 (Bad Request). Error is kinda obvious: ""Error converting value "[object Object]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[TestRotaru.Models.Worker]'. Path 'worker', line 1, position 64.""

Comment: I suspect that your issue is on both Front End and Back End which needs to have some time debugging. Make sure you're passing the right thing that the Backend expects. Rather than that, that's all I can say unless you provide more info

Comment: I changed [value] to [ngValue] and I get the object in the console and I am reaching again the ModelState but I have a new problem to deserialize: :"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"job.worker.Id":["Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[TestRotaru.Models.Worker]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

Comment: Digging right now google on this issue. Also in console my service is displayed like this jobs = {Name: "sadasdsadsa", Description: "fdsfdsfsd", worker: {…}} I am not sure why the dots in the brackets.